# jquery mobile Change Page with slide transition

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

When i change page with slide transition, the changed page resize before the first page complete transition, so the application looks like it bugged,

How can i prevent this auto resize or auto height calcule on page sliding?

PS : I use :

Change page :

```
$.mobile.changePage($page, {changeHash:false, transition: transition});
```

and in css :

```
.ui-page {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set your body scroll top to 0

```
$.mobile.changePage($page, {changeHash:false, transition: transition});
$('body').scrollTop('0'); // set body scroll top to 0
```